# why range object does not automatically generate when we write like this worksheets(1).range("A1")

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbooks(test.xlsm).Worksheets("AAA").Range("a1").Copy 
Workbooks(Practice.xlsm).Sheets("AAA").Range("c1")
```

Why Range object does not auto generate in above query as worksheets auto generate
after workbooks object while writting above code.

Answer (score 4):

A very good question. Here is my understanding of it which I think is the right one but then... It may not be the right one :D

This can be explained in terms of "Earlybinding" and "Latebinding" concept. In latebinding, the object is resolved at runtime and not beforehand and hence Intellisense is not available for *Late Bound* objects.

Type those 2 words separately in the VBE and you will see this

[image]

`Workbooks` object is *Early Bound* (`As Workbook`) and `Worksheets` object is *Late Bound* (`As Object`).

So how do we bypass that? Simply declare your objects. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet '<~~ EARLY BINDING

    Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("AAA")
End Sub
```

Now you will get the intellisense

[image]

Comment: I never made the connection between early and late binding of VBA objects.  Always thought they were both early bound.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.